# pass two variables to the same view Controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I want to pass two different data form two different View Controller (Table1VC - Table2VC) to one distention (MainVC)..

I did that and its worked .. but the problem is :

when I pass the first data there is no problem here 
BUT the problem is when I pass the second data the first one is disappear !!

this is what I did so far :

Table1VC :

```
import UIKit

class Table1ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var city = ["data1" , "data2" , "Data3"]

var passit = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orange

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return city.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = city[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    passit = city[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showtable1", sender: city[indexPath.row])
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let passData1 = segue.destination as! MainVC
        passData1.passcity1 = passit

    }



}
```

Table2VC

```
import UIKit

class passVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   var city2 = ["data1" , "data2" , "Data3"]


var passit = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orange

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return city2.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = city2[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    passit = city2[indexPath.row]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showtable2", sender: city2[indexPath.row])
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let passData2 = segue.destination as! MainVC
    passData2.passcity2 = passit

}



}
```

MainVC

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var passText1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passText2: UITextField!



var passcity1 = ""
var passcity2 = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super .viewDidLoad()



    passText1.text = passcity1
    passText2.text = passcity2


}

}
```

the passed data will be in textfield in MainVC

Comment: You can't segue to the same instance of MainVC from two different view controllers; each segue will create a new instance. If your table views are used to select a value that you want to pass *back* to mainvc then you should read up on unwind segues.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of like the basics of he view stack and the life cycle of the view problem.
When you type the line:

`let passData1 = segue.destination as! MainVC`

it means you want to make **one** instance of the MainVC and want to fill up **that** object's data.

The instant you segue to that controller and come back to the main controller, you have lost the previous object that had the 1st value.

Example:
From VC1:
`let passData1 = segue.destination as! MainVC` -> means telling the compiler make me an object name "passData1", and after this any operation done on **passData1** will affect passData1 **only**

From VC2:
`let passData2 = segue.destination as! MainVC` -> means telling the compiler make me an object name "passData2", and after this any operation done on **passData2** will affect passData2 **only**.

All in all, your objects have changed, hence the previous state of the object is lost. The instant you navigate out of the MainVC for the 1st time, the next time any MainVC object is made, its a fresh copy of MainVC. You will need to set value1 and value2, both.

If you want to maintain the value of passData1, then save the required values somewhere, and when passing passData2, get those values and pass the complete set.

Comment: Thanks for the details answer.. so, how can I do this programmatically ?

Comment: Do you want to go from main to vc1 and then back to main and then to vc2 and then back to main?

Comment: Exactly....u need to define the flow....
For e.g. if u need to take a value from the MainVC and use it in Table1VC then go back and forth, then just keep passing the variables here and there....but that just means u havn't really got the requirements down correctly and your design is flawed.

Comment: What you need to do is instead of trying to pass values here and there, make sure u understand the scope of the variables. If they are application-wide variables, then use the UserDefaults to get you job done. But if it isn't then you will need to define static variables.

Comment: Any movement regarding this?